# Javascript how to change character on textbox?

Tags: javascript, text, replace, onchange

I  want to try this code but author way, and not working form and where is the my wrong code:

```
<input class="copyMe" type="text" />
<input class="copyMe2" type="text" />

$(document).ready(function(){
var input = $(this).val();
var find = ["ş","Ş","ı","I","ğ","Ğ","ü","Ü","ö","Ö","ç","Ç","(",")","/",":",",","&","İ"];
var replace = ["s","s","i","i","g","g","u","u","o","o","c","c","","","-","-","","","i"];
input = input.replaceArray(find, replace);
    $(".copyMe").keyup(function(){
        $(".copyMe2").val($(this).val().input);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where have you defined this String method replaceArray?

Comment: What do you expect, or want, this code to do? Telling us that it's not working is of no help whatsoever if we don't know what it's meant to be doing.

Comment: I want to write first input ö,ş,ç and second input text box will output write o,s,c

Comment: I could provide an answer but first of all a question: do you want to print ö,ş,ç into osc right? because these signs , should be replaced entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var find = ["ş", "Ş", "ı", "I", "ğ", "Ğ", "ü", "Ü", "ö", "Ö", "ç", "Ç", "(", ")", "/", ":", ",", "&", "İ"];
    var replace = ["s", "s", "i", "i", "g", "g", "u", "u", "o", "o", "c", "c", "", "", "-", "-", "", "", "i"];
    $(".copyMe").keyup(function() {
        var input = $(this).val().replaceArray(find, replace);
        $(".copyMe2").val(input);
    });
});
```

but don't forget to extend the String object with your own function that does what you need (useful if there's ever missing functionality):

```
String.prototype.replaceArray = function(find, replace) {
    var replaceString = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
        replaceString = replaceString.split(find[i]).join(replace[i]);
    }
    return replaceString;
};
```

So, the final code will be like that with adding jQuery script

```js
String.prototype.replaceArray = function(find, replace) {
  var replaceString = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
    replaceString = replaceString.split(find[i]).join(replace[i]);
  }
  return replaceString;
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var find = ["ş", "Ş", "ı", "I", "ğ", "Ğ", "ü", "Ü", "ö", "Ö", "ç", "Ç", "(", ")", "/", ":", ",", "&", "İ"];
  var replace = ["s", "s", "i", "i", "g", "g", "u", "u", "o", "o", "c", "c", "", "", "-", "-", "", "", "i"];
  $(".copyMe").keyup(function() {
    var input = $(this).val().replaceArray(find, replace);
    $(".copyMe2").val(input);
  });
});
```

```html
<input class="copyMe" type="text" />
<input class="copyMe2" type="text" />

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, working this code but when i write öşçğ two times this code change first time and second time not change example output öşçğ öşçğ -> oscg öşçğ

Comment: ur welcome @Nikolay just use `.split(find[i]).join(replace[i])` instead of `.replace(find[i], replace[i])` to match all characters.